# mousemove event won't fire on fast mouse movements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have rectangle inside canvas and I want to do something whenever mouse 
hover that rectangle.

with my code mousemove fires only on slow mouse movements but I want to fire mousemove on fast movements too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box ;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        html,body{
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script src="anime.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas') ;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth ;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight  ;
        let rectX = canvas.width/2; 
        let rectY = 0 ;
        let rectWidth = 10 ;
        let rectHeight = canvas.height ;
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') ;
        ctx.beginPath() ;
        ctx.rect(rectX,rectY,rectWidth,rectHeight) ;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black' ;
        ctx.fill() ;
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
            if(e.x >= rectX && e.x <= rectX+rectWidth) {
                console.log('overlap') ;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Input Lag. https://www.vsynctester.com/game.html

Comment: What browser are you testing on?